# css scroll down justify-content flex-end in chating box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox, scrollbar

I want to scrollbar down in chating box like Facebook,Instagram or like a pro chat.
I have already done it by using CSS property called `justify-content: flex-end;` in message box area.
But, When i have uses `justify-content: flex-end;` property in chat box area then the scrollbar is hidden, It's not showing.

I want to done is by CSS, I don't want to do scroll down by `Javascript`. I know how to do scroll down by `Javascript` but, I want like to do it by **JS** .
I want to very professional like pro chating apps OR like a Facebook, Messenger.

Let me know,If you know How it done by Facebook

My Example:

```css
    .conversation .cn-header{
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px #e5e5e5;
        border-radius: 0;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-shrink: 1;
        flex-grow: 1;
        flex-direction: row;
        grid-template-columns:auto;
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-gap: 0;
        grid-template-areas: "profile content";
    }
    .conversation .cn-header .profile{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;    
    }
    .conversation .cn-header .picture-link{
        grid-area: profile;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 80px;
        height: auto;
        padding: 10px 0;
    }
    .conversation .cn-header .picture-link .profile-picture{
        background: url(https://analiq.vip//upload/images/2_1630685233_287449760.jpg);
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 60px;
        width: 60px;
        border-radius: 100px;
    }
    .conversation .cn-header .content .name{
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #2f2f2f;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
    .conversation .cn-header .option .nagivation{
        cursor: pointer;
        display: flex;
        background: #f9f9f9;
        color: #435b66;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        border-radius: 100px;
        padding: 3px;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .conversation .cn-header .content .active-status{
        color: #00d500;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
    .conversation .message-content{
        height: calc(100vh - 100px);
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-grow: 1;
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message{
        padding: 5px 10px; 
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message-row{
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        height: calc(100vh - 150px);
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message-row .text{
        line-height: normal;
        display: block;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message-row .incoming,
    .conversation .message-content .message-row .outgoing{
        margin: 5px 8px 5px 0px;
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message-row .outgoing{
        align-self: flex-end;
        display: inherit;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        background: #2196f3;
        color: #ffff;
        padding: 5px 16px;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message-row .incoming{
        align-self: flex-start;
        display: inherit;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        background: #f1f1f1;
        color: #050505;
        padding: 5px 16px;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message-form{
        display: grid;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-content: flex-start;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        grid-template-columns:90% 23px;
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-gap:0;
        grid-template-areas: "input-field tools submit";
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message-form .tools{
        grid-area: tools;
        display: grid;
        grid-auto-flow: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        align-content: center;
        flex-direction: row;
        row-gap: 10px;
        column-gap: 10px;
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message-form .tools div{
        display: flex;
        color: #6c6c6c;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message-form .tools div:hover{
        color: #2196f3;
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message-form .input-field{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        background: #f7f7f7;
        border-radius: 100px;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message-form .input-field input[type=text]{
        background: inherit;
        border: inherit;
        border-radius: 0;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        outline: 0;
        width: 100%;
        padding-right: 15px;
        font-size: 18px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message-form .input-field .emoji{
        display: flex;
        color: #6c6c6c;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message-form .input-field .emoji:hover{
        color: #2196f3;
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message-form .submit{
        grid-area: submit;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message-form .submit button[type=submit]{
        background: none;
        color: #9e9e9e;
        border: 0;
        outline: 0;
        display: flex;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="conversation" role="conversation">
    <div class="message-content" role="content">
        <div class="message">
            <div class="message-row"> 
                <div class="outgoing">
                    <div class="text">Hi</div>
                </div> 
                <div class="incoming">
                    <div class="text">Hi</div>
                </div> 
                <div class="outgoing">
                    <div class="text">How are you ?</div>
                </div> 
                <div class="incoming">
                    <div class="text">I am fine.</div>
                </div> 
                <div class="incoming">
                    <div class="text">and you?</div>
                </div> 
                <div class="outgoing">
                    <div class="text">Thanks! I am also fine</div>
                </div> 
                <div class="incoming">
                    <div class="text">How are you doing</div>
                </div>
                <div class="outgoing">
                    <div class="text">Nothing special</div>
                </div>
                <div class="outgoing">
                    <div class="text">I am just doing code for my new apps</div>
                </div>
                <div class="incoming">
                    <div class="text">WOW!! </div>
                </div>
                <div class="incoming">
                    <div class="text">What that's the name of the app?</div>
                </div>
                <div class="outgoing">
                    <div class="text">Quick Sender</div>
                </div> 
                <div class="outgoing">
                    <div class="text">Nothing! Have you take evening foods?</div>
                </div>
                <div class="incoming">
                    <div class="text">Not yet. I'll goto outside</div>
                </div> 

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form">
            <form method="post" autocomplete="off" class="message-form">

                <div class="input-field">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Type a message" name="message">
                    <div class="emoji">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-emoji-wink" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                          <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
                          <path d="M4.285 9.567a.5.5 0 0 1 .683.183A3.498 3.498 0 0 0 8 11.5a3.498 3.498 0 0 0 3.032-1.75.5.5 0 1 1 .866.5A4.498 4.498 0 0 1 8 12.5a4.498 4.498 0 0 1-3.898-2.25.5.5 0 0 1 .183-.683zM7 6.5C7 7.328 6.552 8 6 8s-1-.672-1-1.5S5.448 5 6 5s1 .672 1 1.5zm1.757-.437a.5.5 0 0 1 .68.194.934.934 0 0 0 .813.493c.339 0 .645-.19.813-.493a.5.5 0 1 1 .874.486A1.934 1.934 0 0 1 10.25 7.75c-.73 0-1.356-.412-1.687-1.007a.5.5 0 0 1 .194-.68z"/>
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </div>
 

                <div class="submit">
                    <button type="submit" class="send">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="43" height="43" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-telegram" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zM8.287 5.906c-.778.324-2.334.994-4.666 2.01-.378.15-.577.298-.595.442-.03.243.275.339.69.47l.175.055c.408.133.958.288 1.243.294.26.006.549-.1.868-.32 2.179-1.471 3.304-2.214 3.374-2.23.05-.012.12-.026.166.016.047.041.042.12.037.141-.03.129-1.227 1.241-1.846 1.817-.193.18-.33.307-.358.336a8.154 8.154 0 0 1-.188.186c-.38.366-.664.64.015 1.088.327.216.589.393.85.571.284.194.568.387.936.629.093.06.183.125.27.187.331.236.63.448.997.414.214-.02.435-.22.547-.82.265-1.417.786-4.486.906-5.751a1.426 1.426 0 0 0-.013-.315.337.337 0 0 0-.114-.217.526.526 0 0 0-.31-.093c-.3.005-.763.166-2.984 1.09z"/>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the overflow-y property to scroll of message container and custom design the scrollbar using css

```css
  .conversation .cn-header{
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px #e5e5e5;
        border-radius: 0;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-shrink: 1;
        flex-grow: 1;
        flex-direction: row;
        grid-template-columns:auto;
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-gap: 0;
        grid-template-areas: "profile content";
    }
    .conversation .cn-header .profile{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;    
    }
    .conversation .cn-header .picture-link{
        grid-area: profile;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 80px;
        height: auto;
        padding: 10px 0;
    }
    .conversation .cn-header .picture-link .profile-picture{
        background: url(https://analiq.vip//upload/images/2_1630685233_287449760.jpg);
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 60px;
        width: 60px;
        border-radius: 100px;
    }
    .conversation .cn-header .content .name{
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #2f2f2f;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
    .conversation .cn-header .option .nagivation{
        cursor: pointer;
        display: flex;
        background: #f9f9f9;
        color: #435b66;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        border-radius: 100px;
        padding: 3px;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .conversation .cn-header .content .active-status{
        color: #00d500;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
    .conversation .message-content{
        height: calc(100vh - 100px);
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-grow: 1;
    }
       .conversation .message-content .message {
        padding: 5px 10px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }
      .conversation .message-content .message::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }

      .conversation .message-content .message::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: darkgrey;
      }
    .conversation .message-content .message-row{
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        height: calc(100vh - 150px);
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message-row .text{
        line-height: normal;
        display: block;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message-row .incoming,
    .conversation .message-content .message-row .outgoing{
        margin: 5px 8px 5px 0px;
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message-row .outgoing{
        align-self: flex-end;
        display: inherit;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        background: #2196f3;
        color: #ffff;
        padding: 5px 16px;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message-row .incoming{
        align-self: flex-start;
        display: inherit;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        background: #f1f1f1;
        color: #050505;
        padding: 5px 16px;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message-form{
        display: grid;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-content: flex-start;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        grid-template-columns:90% 23px;
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-gap:0;
        grid-template-areas: "input-field tools submit";
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message-form .tools{
        grid-area: tools;
        display: grid;
        grid-auto-flow: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        align-content: center;
        flex-direction: row;
        row-gap: 10px;
        column-gap: 10px;
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message-form .tools div{
        display: flex;
        color: #6c6c6c;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message-form .tools div:hover{
        color: #2196f3;
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message-form .input-field{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        background: #f7f7f7;
        border-radius: 100px;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message-form .input-field input[type=text]{
        background: inherit;
        border: inherit;
        border-radius: 0;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        outline: 0;
        width: 100%;
        padding-right: 15px;
        font-size: 18px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message-form .input-field .emoji{
        display: flex;
        color: #6c6c6c;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message-form .input-field .emoji:hover{
        color: #2196f3;
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message-form .submit{
        grid-area: submit;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    .conversation .message-content .message-form .submit button[type=submit]{
        background: none;
        color: #9e9e9e;
        border: 0;
        outline: 0;
        display: flex;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="conversation" role="conversation">
    <div class="message-content" role="content">
        <div class="message">
            <div class="message-row"> 
                <div class="outgoing">
                    <div class="text">Hi</div>
                </div> 
                <div class="incoming">
                    <div class="text">Hi</div>
                </div> 
                <div class="outgoing">
                    <div class="text">How are you ?</div>
                </div> 
                <div class="incoming">
                    <div class="text">I am fine.</div>
                </div> 
                <div class="incoming">
                    <div class="text">and you?</div>
                </div> 
                <div class="outgoing">
                    <div class="text">Thanks! I am also fine</div>
                </div> 
                <div class="incoming">
                    <div class="text">How are you doing</div>
                </div>
                <div class="outgoing">
                    <div class="text">Nothing special</div>
                </div>
                <div class="outgoing">
                    <div class="text">I am just doing code for my new apps</div>
                </div>
                <div class="incoming">
                    <div class="text">WOW!! </div>
                </div>
                <div class="incoming">
                    <div class="text">What that's the name of the app?</div>
                </div>
                <div class="outgoing">
                    <div class="text">Quick Sender</div>
                </div> 
                <div class="outgoing">
                    <div class="text">Nothing! Have you take evening foods?</div>
                </div>
                <div class="incoming">
                    <div class="text">Not yet. I'll goto outside</div>
                </div> 

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form">
            <form method="post" autocomplete="off" class="message-form">

                <div class="input-field">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Type a message" name="message">
                    <div class="emoji">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-emoji-wink" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                          <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
                          <path d="M4.285 9.567a.5.5 0 0 1 .683.183A3.498 3.498 0 0 0 8 11.5a3.498 3.498 0 0 0 3.032-1.75.5.5 0 1 1 .866.5A4.498 4.498 0 0 1 8 12.5a4.498 4.498 0 0 1-3.898-2.25.5.5 0 0 1 .183-.683zM7 6.5C7 7.328 6.552 8 6 8s-1-.672-1-1.5S5.448 5 6 5s1 .672 1 1.5zm1.757-.437a.5.5 0 0 1 .68.194.934.934 0 0 0 .813.493c.339 0 .645-.19.813-.493a.5.5 0 1 1 .874.486A1.934 1.934 0 0 1 10.25 7.75c-.73 0-1.356-.412-1.687-1.007a.5.5 0 0 1 .194-.68z"/>
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </div>
 

                <div class="submit">
                    <button type="submit" class="send">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="43" height="43" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-telegram" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zM8.287 5.906c-.778.324-2.334.994-4.666 2.01-.378.15-.577.298-.595.442-.03.243.275.339.69.47l.175.055c.408.133.958.288 1.243.294.26.006.549-.1.868-.32 2.179-1.471 3.304-2.214 3.374-2.23.05-.012.12-.026.166.016.047.041.042.12.037.141-.03.129-1.227 1.241-1.846 1.817-.193.18-.33.307-.358.336a8.154 8.154 0 0 1-.188.186c-.38.366-.664.64.015 1.088.327.216.589.393.85.571.284.194.568.387.936.629.093.06.183.125.27.187.331.236.63.448.997.414.214-.02.435-.22.547-.82.265-1.417.786-4.486.906-5.751a1.426 1.426 0 0 0-.013-.315.337.337 0 0 0-.114-.217.526.526 0 0 0-.31-.093c-.3.005-.763.166-2.984 1.09z"/>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```